# Where in my Google maps code can I add Travel Mode to Directions?

Tags: google-maps, mode, directions

I have directions working on my custom map. However I was hoping to add the pulldown I found on Google's Developer site that allows choices like "Bicycle", "Driving", "Transit", "Walking".

---

Here is my code that calls function I know not where they are:

```
var map;
var gdir;
var geocoder = null;
var addressMarker;

function initialize() {
  if (GBrowserIsCompatible()) {      
    map = new GMap2(document.getElementById("map_canvas"));
    gdir = new GDirections(map, document.getElementById("directions"));
    GEvent.addListener(gdir, "load", onGDirectionsLoad);
    GEvent.addListener(gdir, "error", handleErrors);

    setDirections(document.getElementById("fromAddress").value, document.getElementById("toAddress").value, "en_US");
  }
}

function setDirections(fromAddress, toAddress, locale) {
  gdir.load("from: " + fromAddress + " to: " + toAddress,
            { "locale": locale });
}
```

---

and here is the URL and what I *think* is what I need put somewhere in what I have.

--I figure I can test it with just one mode, like "WALKING", first. Then add the pulldown once it works.

=====================================

URL I found this at:
https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/javascript/examples/directions-travel-modes

=========================================

```
    function calcRoute() {
var selectedMode = document.getElementById('mode').value;
var request = {
  origin: haight,
  destination: oceanBeach,
  // Note that Javascript allows us to access the constant
  // using square brackets and a string value as its
  // "property."
  travelMode: google.maps.TravelMode[selectedMode]
};
directionsService.route(request, function(response, status) {
if (status == google.maps.DirectionsStatus.OK) {
  directionsDisplay.setDirections(response);
}
});
}
```

---

This is in the code above and I want to use it 
travelMode: google.maps.TravelMode["WALKING"]

Answer (score 0):

I figured it out. I'm trying to add v3 features/syntax to v2. Doh! (slaps forehead)